# What causes `dpkg-reconfigure` to show nothing (ssl-cert package)?

Tags: debconf

```
$ sudo debconf-show ssl-cert
  make-ssl-cert/title:
  make-ssl-cert/altname:
  make-ssl-cert/vulnerable_prng:
  make-ssl-cert/hostname: localhost
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure ssl-cert
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p low -f dialog ssl-cert
$
```

`dpkg-reconfigure` is expected to re-ask the debconf questions (which were not asked at install time, presumably due to a `low` priority).  But it doesn't in this case.  What causes this?

I'm asking out of curiosity.  Having looked at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/ssl-cert.postinst`, I don't think changing the `hostname` question would affect the installed certificate.  (You have to use `make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil --force-overwrite` instead, as per the [wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/ChangeHostname#Self-signed_SSL_certificate)).

The above results come from a Debian Stretch system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg-reconfigure ssl-cert` doesn’t ask any questions by default because it doesn’t do anything by default. The `postinst` itself only asks questions in some circumstances if it finds a vulnerable snakeoil key. The `make-ssl-cert` script, which is called by `postinst`, aborts quickly if the snakeoil certificate is already installed; even if the snakeoil certificate needs to be installed, `make-ssl-cert` does so without asking any questions.

The only time `make-ssl-cert` asks questions using debconf is when it’s called manually with parameters other than `generate-default-snakeoil`.

Comment: Actually I got the last part wrong, see my update. This whole setup is rather unusual: it uses debconf variables, but only for manual invocations...

Comment: Thanks!  Additionally `dpkg-preconfigure` asks no questions for `ssl-cert`, and this is simply because there is no `ssl-cert.config` script.  More details: [dpkg-preconfigure](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debconf-doc/debconf-devel.7.en.html) [dpkg-reconfigure](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/debconf/debconf.git/tree/dpkg-reconfigure?id=0e170cce7a4f91b5e6bdf5b901654cbf605a942d#n191).